# Rename foreign key system name in SQL Server Management Studio is failing

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, indexing

> The method or operation is not
>   permitted.

I assume this is a permission's issue, but I can't figure out where I would change it. It is strange because I can rename an index with no issue.

EDIT:

If you're looking at a table, and you see "Columns, Keys, Constraints, etc.", this is under Keys, and it is the system name that I presume SQL is using to identify the foreign key name I gave the column.

Comment: did you try removing it and re-creating it? In that case, is it giving the same Error?

Comment: I did try that. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact error you are getting?

Also, generate a script for your change and paste that script into a query window and try it there.  See what the error is.  Note that SSMS GUI stuff is NOT the best place to do stuff like this.

Comment: The method or operation is not permitted (ObjectExplorer)... that is the exact error.

Comment: I second the suggestion to create a script (there's a button for that in the tool bar after you made the change in the SSMS GUI) and then run it in a query window. This should give you a more meaningful error message.